# Configure MySQL to return warning rows

Tags: mysql, sql, utf-8

I'm working on converting a database that has a bunch of latin1 encoded columns into utf8. There are a bunch of rows that are misencoded and need to be converted from latin1 -> utf8 before I migrate the entire column. I wrote a script that identifies problematic rows with the following query:

```
SELECT count(*) as count
FROM `user_profiles` 
WHERE CONVERT(CAST(`last_name` AS binary) USING utf8) IS NULL;
```

Locally, it returns a count of 4,000 rows.  When I run it on production I get an empty result with 4,000 warnings.  There must be some setting that tells MySQL to return warnings normally or something that I'm missing.  Any thoughts?

I've already tried making sure that all the character set variables are set to UTF8.  The server is running mysql 5.5.29 and I'm running 5.6.13 locally.

Comment: try to run SHOW WARNINGS; directly after your select query then it should report you the warnings

Comment: @RaymondNijland that's not what I'm looking for.  My local MySQL returns the actual count.  I want the production database to do the same thing.

Comment: Maybe this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_error_count is set to zero?  maybe youcan set it your self ? SET SESSION max_error_count=some int

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to set the `sql_mode` to a more liberal setting.  Specifically, [STRICT_TRANS_TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_trans_tables) and [NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_engine_substitution) seemed to solve the problem.

You can execute the following command at the begining of your SQL query to make that happen:

```
SET `sql_mode` = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```